# Caesar cipher for loop is looping more than expected

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, cs50, caesar-cipher

**first look at my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
bool only_digits(string s);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2) //if more than two CLA inputs, end program.
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(only_digits(argv[1]) == false) //if func only_digits returns false, exit prog. 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(only_digits(argv[1]) == true) // if func only_digits returns true, print argv[1].
    {
        printf("Text: %s\n", argv[1]);
    }

}
bool only_digits(string s)    //func taking string input and bool output
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)  // loop till strlen(s)
    {
        printf("strlen(s) = %lu\n",strlen(s)); //debug
        printf("s[%d] = %c is alpha\n",i, s[i]);  //debug

        if(isalpha(s[i]) == !0)  //inside loop check each char of string s in isalpha.
        {
            printf("s[i] = %c is alpha\n",s[i]); //debug
            return false;                         //if char is alpha, return false to function
        }

    }
    return true;    // if not returned false inside loop, return true.

}
```

My for loop runs from i=1 to i=strlen() then loops again to from i=0 to i=strlen() that is it loops 2*strlen() times instead of strlen() times.
Here is the CLA and output

```
caesar/ $ ./caesar b2
strlen(s) = 2
s[0] = b is alpha
strlen(s) = 2
s[1] = 2 is alpha
strlen(s) = 2
s[0] = b is alpha
strlen(s) = 2
s[1] = 2 is alpha
Text: b2
```

Point Wise Questions:

1. Why is my if condition inside for loop not working as expected (return false when encountering an alphabet char.)?
2. Why is  my for loop iterating twice times more than expected?
3. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You call the function twice ....

Comment: @Mat `!` is the logical not, i.e. `!0` will not produce an int with all bits set. You are probably thinking about `~0`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `only_digits` in main twice due to conditions in these if statements

```
    if(only_digits(argv[1]) == false) //if func only_digits returns false, exit prog. 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(only_digits(argv[1]) == true) // if func only_digits returns true, print argv[1].
    {
        printf("Text: %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
```

This if statement

```
if(isalpha(s[i]) == !0)
```

is equivalent to the statement

```
if(isalpha(s[i]) == 1)
```

However it is not necessary that the function `isalpha` will return exactly `1` in case when an alpha character is encountered. It just returns a non-zero value. You need at least to write

```
if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) != 0 )
```

or just

```
if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) )
```

Pay attention to that the string can also contain other symbols excepts alpha and digit symbols.

Also there is no great sense to call the function strlen several times.

Using your parameter declaration the function `only_digits` can be defined the following way

```
bool only_digits( string s ) 
{
    while ( *s && isdigit( ( unsigned char ) *s ) ) ++s;

    return *s == '\0';
}
```